# Bootstrap table using 'checkAll' method only checks the checkboxes in the current page

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-table

I have a bootstrap table in my HTML5 page.

When using  `$('#bk-table').bootstrapTable('checkAll')`

Only the checkboxes in current page r checked.

How could I check all the checkboxes in all page?

My bootstrap table:

```
 <form>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <table  contenteditable='true' class="table table-bordered table-xl" width="100%"  cellspacing="0" style="font-size: 1.0rem;"
                id="bk-table"
                data-toggle="table"
                data-toolbar="#toolbar"
                data-cookie="true"
                data-cookie-id-table="materialId"
                data-show-columns="true"           
                data-show-export="true"           
                data-height="1650"
                data-click-to-select="true"
                data-id-field="id"
                data-show-footer="true"
                data-url="/api/materials/"
                data-query-params="queryParams"
                data-remember-order="true"
                data-pagination="true"
                data-side-pagination="client"
                data-total-field="count"
                data-data-field="results">
          
            <thead class="thead-dark" >

            <tr contenteditable='true'>
                <th data-field="state" name="checkbox" class="data-checkbox"  id="data-checkbox"  data-checkbox="true" ></th>
                <th class ='courseCode' data-field="courseCode"  data-formatter="renderCourse">Course Code</th>

            </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </form>
```

My button event:

```
    <button class="button" type="button" onclick="select_all();">Select All</button>
<script>
            function select_all()
            {           
                $('#bk-table').bootstrapTable('checkAll')
            }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

bootstrapTable('checkAll') is for Check/Uncheck all current page rows. For selecting all the pages, first you load data `let data = $("#bk-table").bootstrapTable('getData');` and iterate though data object & update the id field `state` (because `data-field="state"` for check box) value to `true` in the object array data then you reload table with your updated data `$('#bk-table').bootstrapTable('load', data);`

Please find sample updated data object array:

```
 data = [{"id":1,"courseCode":"Item 1","state":true},{"id":2,"courseCode":"Item 2","state":true},{"id":3,"courseCode":"Item 3","state":true}];
```

```js
function select_all()
            {           
                let data = $("#bk-table").bootstrapTable('getData');  //getting table data
                for(let i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                           data[i]['state'] = true;
                }
                $('#bk-table').bootstrapTable('load', data); //reloading table data after updation
            }
```

```html
<button class="button" type="button" onclick="select_all();">Select All</button>
```

up votes will be appreciated!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Noted. Will share detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this by turning the pagination off, then selecting all the boxes and then turning pagination back on:

```
       <div id="importClientsToolbar">
           <h5 id="importClientsToolbar" class="m-0 text-primary"><font color="purple">Select Clients to Import</font></h5>
           <button class="btn btn-default btn-outline-primary" id="check">Check All</button>
           <button class="btn btn-default btn-outline-primary" id="uncheck">Uncheck All</button>
       </div>

      <table id="selectClientsToImport"
             class="table table-borderless sortable"
             bgcolor="#FFFFFF"
             data-toolbar="#importClientsToolbar"
             data-toolbar-align="left"
             data-search="true"
             data-click-to-select="true"
             data-checkbox-header="false"
             data-toggle="table"
             data-response-handler="responseHandler"
             data-pagination="true">

<script>
    var checkAll = false
    $(function () {
        $('#check').click(function () {
            $('#selectClientsToImport').bootstrapTable('togglePagination')
            checkAll = true
            $('#selectClientsToImport').bootstrapTable('checkAll')
            $('#selectClientsToImport').bootstrapTable('togglePagination')
        })
        $('#uncheck').click(function () {
            $('#selectClientsToImport').bootstrapTable('togglePagination')
            checkAll = false
            $('#selectClientsToImport').bootstrapTable('uncheckAll')
            $('#selectClientsToImport').bootstrapTable('togglePagination')
        })
    })
    function responseHandler(res) {
        res.rows.forEach(function (item) {
            item.state = checkAll
        })
        return res
    }
</script>
```